# How to call the method finished() to exit the whole PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I use the official SettingsActivity as my activity's templete,and my preferenceactivity have two static class "preferencefragment1" and "preferencefragment2".

While the App click the headers of the preferenceactivity, it switch to the specified preferencefragment.Then I call the finished() method in the onkeydown() method with the KEYCODE_BACK event.It will back to the headers view.
However,what I want is it back to the mainactivity from preferencefragment view,make the whole PreferenceActivity to finish instead of just the preferencefragment1 view.

Because I want to use the the preferenceActivity to set the parameters of a bluetooth comunication device,and after parameters finished setting, it can immediately send the parameteres to the deivce in the onActivityResult() method.
But now, I must click the BACK button twice to back to the mainactivity.Is that a possible to skip the header view to show or jump into the preferencefragment view directly?
[program flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnHe3.png)

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.SwitchPreference;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.List;
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static List<Header> headers;
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();
            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);
            }
            if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
                editTextPreference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            if (preference instanceof SwitchPreference) {
                SwitchPreference switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) preference;
                switchPreference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Confirm to update system paras?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELED", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        System.out.print(resultCode);
    }

    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_system);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
           // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
        headers=target;
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || SystemPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);

    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    public static class SystemPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_system);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_ip"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_port"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_output1_level"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_output2_level"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_output3_level"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_noportrait"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_closeeye"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_yawn"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_key_distract"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

        /*
        @Override
        public void onStop()
        {
            super.onStop();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Confirm to update system paras?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   SystemPreferenceFragment.this.getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELED", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SystemPreferenceFragment.this.getActivity().setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            this.getActivity().finish();
        }*/

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class RealtimePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_realtime);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity().finish();` to finish the activity

or

expose a method using interface from fragment to activity to notify back is being pressed

Comment: I guess it has two activities, PreferenceActivity A for show headers  and the PreferenceActivity B for show the setting pages. A start B , not the preferenceActivity A switch to the preferenceFragment B

Comment: I dont understand the flow can you provide a flow diagram of activity

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!

step 1:In the MainActivity, add flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" to the Intent, then start the SettingsActivity.

step 2: Override the onBuildStartFragmentIntent() method of SettingsActivity(PreferenceActivity) for adding flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT,so that the activityresult can return to the MainActivity.

```
Like below: @Override

public Intent onBuildStartFragmentIntent (String fragmentName,
                                       Bundle args,
                                       int titleRes,
                                       int shortTitleRes)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClass(this, getClass());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, fragmentName);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS, args);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_TITLE, titleRes);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_SHORT_TITLE, shortTitleRes);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);//the new statement
        return intent;
    }
```